# Error while creating index on geometry column

Tags: mysql, indexing, geospatial

I have a table with spatial column(data type geometry) and with around 450k rows. When i tried to add a spatial index on this column, it returns an error as "All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL".

The query to create index is

```
create spatial index spatIdx on table_name(ogc_geom)
```

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Where these NULL parts came from?
3. If its in my spat data how can i remove it (i tried with is null).

Comment: it returns count as zero

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html), it states, "Currently, columns in spatial indexes must be declared NOT NULL". My guess is the column `ogc_geom` is allowed to have `NULL`.  Try:

`ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN ogc_geom .... NOT NULL`

Any column you create a spatial index on must be defined with "NOT NULL", or else you will get an error.

Comment: could you give the "DESCRIBE table_name" output?

Answer (score -2):

how about if you use the "ALTER TABLE" statement instead to update your table structure and add the index into it.

try to check the sysntax from this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html